# How to realize a curved header with shadow border, without using images

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to build a header like you can see in the code example below. In this example I am using 3 different background images. **But I do not want to use images**, because they becomes ugly on mobile devices with high resolution displays.

Are there other possibilities to realize such header with pure CSS or maybe with vector techniques (SVG, clip or similar)?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  height: 50px;
}
#header .bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#header .bg > div {
  float: left;
}
#header .bg .left {
  width: calc(25% - 59px);
  height: 117px;
  background-image: url("http://fs5.directupload.net/images/161026/hkplooah.png");
}
#header .bg .curve {
  width: 59px;
  height: 116px;
  background-image: url("http://fs5.directupload.net/images/161026/kk3zkqox.png");
}
#header .bg .right {
  width: 75%;
  height: 68px;
  background-image: url("http://fs5.directupload.net/images/161026/vaucnr84.png");
}
#content {
  height: 200px;
  background: #cee4fa;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="bg">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="curve"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this using `filter`, `feGaussianBlur`, and `feMerge`?

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="ExampleForStackOverflow" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="100%" height="10%" viewBox="0 0 800 400" enable-background="new 0 0 800 400" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
        <filter id="slight-glow">
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=
                        "0 0 0 0   0
                         0 0 0 0   0
                         0 0 0 0   0
                         0 0 0 0.7 0"/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3.5" result="coloredBlur"/>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
          </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
<linearGradient id="SOExample1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="399.5005" y1="83.313" x2="399.5005" y2="2.9984">
 <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#CCCCCC"/>
 <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
</linearGradient>
<path filter="url(#slight-glow)" fill="url(#SOExample1)" stroke="#555555" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M-0.5,0.5v82h158c18.625-1,23.751-16.5,28.023-24.384
 c5.414-9.991,13.424-19.616,22.901-19.616H799.5v-38H-0.5z"/>
</svg>
```

> [CodePen to tinker with and tweak for concept refinement...](http://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/VKNERW)

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Realy impressive! Just one thing: Is it possible that the header height is constant, independet from the width?

Comment: @AndyTschiersch Depends on the consistency of where the gradient start/stop points are and what you're using to cast the shadow effect. May have to separate into separate Path's or use javascript to manipulate the path data accordingly.